# how to allocate unique number to user from database

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

1.i have two tables seatnumber in which predefined data is available on basis of class name
2. in booking table i want to allocate this number for particluar booking. say if one booking id is generating for 3 passenger then in this table say 1,2,3 seat number should allocate

```
CREATE TABLE SEATNUMBER
   (    "SEAT_NO" NUMBER,
         "CLASS_NAME" VARCHAR2, 
    "ACTIVE" NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   )  

   CREATE TABLE BOOKING
   (        booking_id number,
            seatnumber number    
       )
```

active column in seatnumber table is for showing whether seat is already allocated to some booking id or no
1 is for not allocate
2 is for allocate

Answer (score 0):

To find unused seat numbers you can do something like:

```
SELECT s.SEAT_NO as UNUSED_SEAT_NO
  FROM SEATNUMBER s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING b
    ON (b.SEATNUMBER = s.SEAT_NO)
  WHERE b.BOOKING_ID IS NULL AND
        s.ACTIVE = 1;
```

I didn't understand your comment about the ACTIVE column.  Here I'm interpreting your comment to mean that a value of 1 indicates that the seat is available to be allocated, and that 2 means it is already allocated.  If I've got that wrong just change the query to use `s.ACTIVE = 2`.

Share and enjoy.